# Laravel response's datatype varying over different server

Tags: laravel, api, types, response

I hosted my Laravel API project on two servers. I am getting different responses from different servers. From one server I am getting an Integer response, while other servers responding String. The expected response is Integer. I put an example below.

Server 1's response

```
{
   is_active: 1
}
```

Server 2's response

```
{
   is_active: '1'
}
```

Code and Database Structure are exactly the same in both servers. Does anyone have any solution for this?

Note: I heard, by installing the *mysqlnd* extension in apache server will solve this datatype issue. I installed it, But the issue didn't solved yet.

Comment: [Cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting) it to integer

Comment: @brombeer, that is a good solution. Thanks. 
but do you have any idea, why this issue is happening?

Comment: I have no clue to be honest ;)

Comment: ok... @brombeer

Comment: the same thing happened to me. is there any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have an also same error but its resolved
On your server, disable the "pdo_mysql `extension and enable the "nd_pdo_mysql` extension.

If the issue is still not resolved, then compare the PhpMyInfo > MySQL section.